# Is there any way to use the command line to debug an ERB file?

Tags: ruby, debugging, erb

Is there any way to use the command line to debug an ERB file? I would like to know if there is any way to get rdebug or rdebug-ide to do this.

Comment: Why do you need a line-by-line debugger for ERb?

Comment: Im building a web based front end for building Ruby applications and it will have an ERB line by line debugger, so I will need to call a debugger on the server side. If I can't find one then I will just convert the ERB to Ruby and match up the Ruby code lines to the ERB file to make the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you monkey patch the method you need, and you include a call to `debugger`? You'd need the `ruby-debug` gem for the `debugger` method.

Comment: I have since stopped trying to do this, but at the time I was going to do something like that. Its just s shame it had not already been done

Answer (score 0):

There probably is, but I have been doing the equiv of print.

puts YAML::dump(variable)

Comment: Yes, I can do this, but I'm trying to build a web page front end for the ERB debugger, so really need something that can do it programmatically. So far I can't find anything like ruby-debug. I have heard netbeans can do it but its not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like, `STDERR.puts "Debug message"` and it'll appear in the console window or in your log if it's Rails or Sinatra.

Comment: This can be done in standard Ruby too, to print debug statements, but I'm looking for a debugger which allows you to manually step through the code programatically.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you can do this.